# Background timed task iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app in which I want to make a network call (syncing purpose) on an hourly basis. Even when the app is in the terminated state. How can I achieve this?

There is no UI Update involved anywhere, I just need to update local database and the cloud storage file.

Comment: There are lots of ways you could do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: In the most general case, this is impossible, because it's explicitly forbidden by Apple. There are exceptions, however, for specific types of applications. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1 ("Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks") and see if your requirements fall into one of the supported cases. The implementation details depend on which category applies.

Comment: @RobNapier I read the document but I think my sync belongs to the *Background fetch* Background mode. I have fetch some data at repeated intervals. There is no UI update involved, its just to update the local database which is very essential.

Comment: You can't guarantee that you'll be allowed to fetch data at specific intervals. That's up to the user, and the OS will tell you when you're allowed, and it will be opportunistic (i.e. when it's convenient for the device, not for you). If your design requires a very specific update frequency, and you don't fall into one of the other categories (like VoIP), then you'll have to redesign. Apple intentionally does not allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

[developer apple BackgroundExecution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
    background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        while(YES)
        { 

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:your_sleep_time];

        }
    });
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Multitasking Not Supported");
}
```

**We've created a new background task and add a new thread to it, so you can sleep the thread freely :)
I Hope I've help you**